# Hazards of not protection shared variables in a threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to understand the hazards of not locking shared variables in a threaded (or shared memory) environment. It is easy to argue that if you are doing two or more dependent operations on a variable it is important to hold some lock first. The typical example is the increment operation, which first reads the current value before adding one and writing back.

But what if you only have one writer (and lots of readers) and the write is not dependent on the previous value. So I have one thread storing a timestamp offset once every second. The offset holds the difference between local time and some other time base. A lot of readers use this offset to timestamp events and getting a read lock for each time is a little expensive. In this situation I don't care if the reader gets the value just before the write or just after, as long as the reader don't get garbage (that is an offset that was never set).

Say that the variable is a 32 bit integer. Is it possible to get a garbage read of the variable in the middle of a write? Or are writing a 32 bit integer an atomic operation? Will it depend on the Os or hardware? What a about a 64 bit integer on a 32 bit system?

What about shared memory instead of threading?

Comment: "Shared memory" is not an alternative to "threading". Possibly your only alternative here is message passing instead of shared memory, in which case each thread has their own timestamp which is updated whenever they receive a message. There are plenty of threadsafe algorithms for message passing (AFAIK, every OS provides one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit read/write is guaranteed to be atomic if it is aligned to it's size (on 486 and later) and unaligned but within a cache line (on P6 and later). Most compilers will guarantee stack (local, assuming C/C++) variables are aligned.

A 64-bit read/write is guaranteed to be atomic if it is aligned (on Pentium and later), however, this relies on the compiler generating a single instruction (for example, popping a 64-bit float from the FPU or using MMX). I expect most compilers will use two 32-bit accesses for compatibility, though it is certainly possible to check (the disassembly) and it may be possible to coerce different handling.

The next issue is caching and memory fencing. However, the effect of ignoring these is that some threads may see the old value even though it has been updated. The value won't be invalid, simply out of date (by microseconds, probably). If this is critical to your application, you will have to dig deeper, but I doubt it is.

(Source: [Intel Software Developer Manual Volume 3A](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/))

Comment: Obviously different processors may have different behaviour, so try and find an equivalent document to the system programming guide for whatever you are using.

Comment: The memory alignment is the important clue here I think. From this it sounds that writing a 32 bit integer on a x86 system is atomic if the variable is aligned (which can be done explicitly in the code) and then it should be safe to access the variable without taking a lock as long as I don't mind getting possible stale data due to register caching.

Comment: That's basically it, though as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149524/hazards-of-not-protection-shared-variables-in-a-threaded-environment/4149715#4149715 points out you can cover yourself a bit more by adding `volatile` (in C/C++) to the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a 64-bit integer on a 32-bit system is not atomic, and you could have incorrect data if you don't take a lock.

As an example, if your integer is

```
0x00000000 0xFFFFFFFF
```

and you are going to write the next int in sequence, you want to write:

```
0x00000001 0x00000000
```

But if you read the value after one of the ints is written and before the other is, then you could read

```
0x00000000 0x00000000
```

or

```
0x00000001 0xFFFFFFFF
```

which are wildly different than the correct value.

If you want to work without locks, you have to be very certain what constitutes an atomic operation on your OS/CPU/compiler combination.

Comment: In some languages there are other issues, too. For example, Java does not guarantee that different threads will see the same data unless that data is protected by a `synchronized` block. A reader thread can still see a stale value even after the writer thread has completed its operation.

Comment: That is part of my question. How do I know what operations are atomic on my OS/CPU/compiler. Say for instance that I want to write a 32 bit integer on a 32 bit system for a program written in c and compiled with gcc running on Linux.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: In this case I really don't care if the reader sees stale data. Stale data are ok, but garbage (as described in this answer with a 64 bit integer) is not.

Comment: @Vegar Fair enough. I just wanted to point out that there are sometimes other issues that may be applicable for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

In additions to the above comments, beware the register bank in a slightly more general setting. You may end up updating only the cpu register and not really write it back to main memory right away. Or the other way around where you use a cached register copy while the original value in memory has been updated. Some languages have a `volatile` keyword to mark a variable as "read-always-and-never-locally-register-cache".

The *memory model* of your language is important. It describes exactly under what conditions a given value is shared among several threads. Either this is the rules of the CPU architecture you are executing on, or it is determined by a virtual machine in which the language is running. Java for instance has a separate memory model you can look at to figure out what exactly to expect.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on hardware and how you are talking to it.  If you are writing assembler, you will know exactly what you get as processor manuals will tell you which operations are atomic and under what conditions.  For example, in the Intel Pentium, 32-bit reads are atomic if the address is aligned, but not otherwise.

If you are working on any level above that, it will depend on how that ultimately gets translated into machine code.  Be that a compiler, interpreter, or virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The platform you run on determines the size of atomic reads/writes. Generally, a 32-bit (register) platform only supports 32-bit atomic operations. So, if you are writing more than 32-bits, you will probably have to use some other mechanism to coordinate access to that shared data.

One mechanism is to double or triple buffer the actual data and use a shared index to determine the "latest" version:

```
write(blah)
{
    new_index= ...; // find a free entry in the global_data array.
    global_data[new_index]= blah;
    WriteBarrier(); // write-release
    global_index= new_index;
}

read()
{
    read_index= global_index;
    ReadBarrier(); // read-acquire
    return global_data[read_index];
}
```

You need the memory barriers to ensure that you don't read from `global_data[...]` until after you read `global_index` and you don't write to `global_index` until after you write to `global_data[...]`.

This is a little awful since you can also run into the ABA issue with preemption, so don't use this directly.

Answer (score 0):

Platforms often provide atomic read/write access (enforced at the hardware level) to primitive values (32-bit or 64-bit,as in your example) - see [the Interlocked* APIs on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

This can avoid the use of a heavier weight lock for threadsafe variable or member access, but should not be mixed up with other types of lock on the same instance or member.  In other words, don't use a `Mutex` to mediate access in one place and use `Interlocked*` to modify or read it in another.